# IIS 6 generate request ID for log and header

Tags: iis, logging, request, iis-6

We're using IIS 6 to serve static content and to route to dynamically generated pages on another server. Now we would like to add some logging which can be followed throughout a request, so for each request we want to:

- generate a unique ID (UUID or similar),
- print to some type of log using the generated ID,
- add the generated ID to the request header when passing it on to our back-end server (so we can follow the logs there as well).

Is there some type of script I can use? Or do I need to build some type of plug-in? (I don't know what options I have and where to start.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to create an ISAPI filter in C. I'm not done, but thus far I've managed to get this filter loaded into the IIS (compiled using MSVC2010 Express+Win7.1 SDK):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <httpfilt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

BOOL WINAPI GetFilterVersion(PHTTP_FILTER_VERSION pVer)
{
    const char* desc = "Some filter, version 0.1";
    pVer->dwFilterVersion = HTTP_FILTER_REVISION;
    pVer->dwFlags = SF_NOTIFY_PREPROC_HEADERS | SF_NOTIFY_ORDER_HIGH;
    strncpy(pVer->lpszFilterDesc, desc, SF_MAX_FILTER_DESC_LEN);
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI HttpFilterProc(PHTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT pfc, DWORD NotificationType, LPVOID pvNotification)
{
    char uuid[50];
    if (NotificationType == SF_NOTIFY_PREPROC_HEADERS)
    {
        PHTTP_FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS lHeaders = (PHTTP_FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS)pvNotification;
        GUID guid;
        CoCreateGuid(&guid);
        _snprintf(uuid, sizeof(uuid), "{%08X-%04hX-%04hX-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}", guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
        // ToDo: print the UUID in the log as well.
        lHeaders->AddHeader(pfc, "Log-Request-ID:", uuid);
    }
    return SF_STATUS_REQ_NEXT_NOTIFICATION; 
}
```

and export them in a .def file:

```
LIBRARY   "log_request_filter"
EXPORTS
    GetFilterVersion
    HttpFilterProc
```

The DLL now loads in IIS6. Remains to get a log row out (or modify the redirect log row in some lower-prio filter) and to get the header working.